# How to engage editMode, info disappears when edit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of users/contacts with an edit and delete button at the end of each line. The delete button works as it should, but when the edit button is clicked, the line of information disappears and does not engage edit mode. The line of info returns when the page is refreshed. I have been working on this for a while, but cannot seem to figure out why this is happening. I have compared it to the rest of the code for the website where the edit mode does work, and it all checks out, but this is still happening. I have tried console.log-ing and there are no reported errors. I have posted this before: [Table row disappears when the edit button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975113/table-row-disappears-when-the-edit-button-is-clicked)
Does anyone have any theories as to why this is happening?

HTML code:

```
<template name="SingleContact">
  {{#if editMode}}
    <form class="editForm">
      <td class="input-field">
        <input id="full_name" name="full_name" value="{{fullname}}" 
        type="text" class="validate" />
      </td>
      <td class="input-field">
        <input id="email" name="email" value="{{email}}" 
        type="email" class="validate" />
      </td>
      <td class="input-field">
        <input id="phone" name="phone" value="{{phone}}" type="tel" 
        class="validate" />
      </td>
      {{#if customerIsEnterprise}}
        <td>
          <p>
            {{#if clientContact}}
            <input type="checkbox" id="primaryContact" 
            name="primaryContact" checked="checked" />
            {{else}}
            <input type="checkbox" id="primaryContact" 
            name="primaryContact" />
            {{/if}}
            <label for="primaryContact">Primary Contact?</label>
          </p>
        </td>
      {{/if}}
    </form>
  {{else}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{fullname}}</td>
      ...
       <td class="button-cell"><a class="edit btn waves-effect 
       waves-light" href="#">Edit<i class="material-icons 
       right">mode_edit</i></a></td>
       ...      
    </tr>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS code:

```
import { Contacts } from 
'../../../../../imports/api/Contacts/Contacts';

Template.SingleContact.onCreated(function(){
  this.editMode = new ReactiveVar(false);
  Blaze._allowJavascriptUrls();
});

Template.SingleContact.helpers({
  editMode: function(){
    return Template.instance().editMode.get();
  }
});

Template.SingleContact.events({

  //delete contact
  'click .delete'(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      Meteor.call("removeContact", this._id);
      sAlert.error('Contact removed successfully!');
  },

  //engage edit mode
  'click .edit': function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    template.editMode.set(!template.editMode.get());
  },

});
```

The bare minimum HTML:

```
<template name="SingleContact">
  {{#if editMode}}
    <form class="editForm">

      <tr class="input-field">
        <input id="full_name" name="full_name" value="{{fullname}}" type="text" class="validate" />
      </tr>
    </form>
  {{else}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{fullname}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
      <td>{{phone}}</td>
      <td>{{phone2}}</td>
  <td class="button-cell"><a class="edit btn waves-effect waves-light" href="#">Edit<i class="material-icons right">mode_edit</i></a></td>
      <td class="button-cell"><a class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn red" href="#contactModal{{_id}}">Delete<i class="material-icons right">delete</i></a></td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Your description is really hard to understand as long as there is no code of the HTML part of the Template. Please add it (excluded unrelated parts) .

Comment: HTML added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have an HTML issue:

- the 2 blocks of your `{{#if editMode}}` template condition are not equivalent: the `{{else}}` block correctly contains the `<tr>` table row, whereas the other does not.
- a `<table>` cannot have direct children other than thead, tbody, tfooter, or directly tr. Most browsers will eliminate (hoist out) elements not in this list, which may apply to your `<form>` tag. The usual workaround is to place a single form wrapping the entire table, or to get rid of the form tag if you do not actually rely on it to http post the form data (but you also lose the "press enter key" to submit form feature), which is probably your case since you handle your application with Meteor and probably do not expect to reload your page to record the modifications.

Comment: Thank you! I have tested different html patterns. I have the bare minimum HTML updated in the question portion. I have taken out the <form> tag and tried changing it to <div> tags, etc. But unfortunately I am still getting the same result. When I click the edit btn, the <tr> of info just disappears. And it's just that row that disappears, not the whole display

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you have tried and what result you get. In your new HTML, do not forget <td> cells under your <tr> row, and get rid of the <form>.

Comment: BTW the usual implementation for inline row edit is to switch (if/else) the _content_ of each cell (text/input) in the row rather than changing the <tr> row.